# Seeking advice to improve the design of my productivity app

Tags: critique, applications

I'm developing a productivity dashboard for Google Chrome called  [Beautab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/beautab-productivity-dash/cnpicfljkbmnahnbhfojphebedmmbaij?hl=en-GB), which has about 500 users. This is my original design, which is heavily influenced by a similar app called [Momentum](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=en):

[image: Beautab (not-so) original design]

And my new design looks like this:

[image: Beautab new design]

I've tried to organise the various elements better and keep a strong visual hierarchy, but I've lost the "Good evening" greeting and most of the elements have ended up grouped into one corner.

- Does it seem out of balance? Could the elements be placed better to improve the overall balance?
- I'm not a professional designer -- are there any design conventions I'm currently breaking or should be following?
- Would you consider this an improvement on the original design?

Beautab uses lots of different background images, so designing around the images shown isn't necessary.

Comment: I think this is a UX related question.

Comment: To judge the visuals, we need to understand the intent and purpose of all the elements. As hsawires states, there's likely a UX question that needs to be addressed first (or in tandem). Also, while I like your design, it's very clearly borrows heavily from the other app. I don't think you're necessarily plagiarizing, but I'd strongly suggest you go back and spend some time and see if you can come at it with a very different aesthetic. See if you can do something good, but different.

Comment: I really appreciate your comments, thank you. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "a UX related question"? Again, I'm not a professional -- what exactly would this question be?

@DA01, it's true that the general features of the design are still similar to Momentum (big wallpaper image, prominent clock, slightly transparent white elements), but these are all frequent design features of many of the apps in my category. I don't want to change the design radically, or I risk alienating my current users. In the future I'll try not to copy another app so closely in the first place. :)

Comment: @ChristopherDrifter I think the similarities go a bit further than that, though...you're using the same icons. Same typeface. Same type color. Same general positioning of element. Same content. Same visual technique to show event (reversed text on translucent bar). I get that these are common thing, and a lot of apps have them. I'm just saying that I don't see a huge difference between these two and maybe it makes sense from a branding/market position to really try and come up with something visually different to stand out amongst the competition.

Comment: As for UX, what I'm getting at is that design is as much about the *why* as it is the *what*. Why did you position the things on the page like you did? What is most important to the user? What is second most important? What is the purpose of the app? How is a user going to use this app? Etc.

Comment: I'm sorry @DA01, I wasn't clear: both screenshots are of my app Beautab. That's why the icons and typeface are the same. :) You can see what Momentum looks like  [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/momentum/laookkfknpbbblfpciffpaejjkokdgca?hl=en).

Comment: @ChristopherDrifter Oh! Then disregard all that I said about them looking the same! :) They are definitely different. I like the direction yours is going in.